# How to get matching string by performing search on Lucene?

Tags: php, perl, lucene

I would like to know how can I get the matching string results by performing search on a Lucene index ?

I have tried to install the Perl module [`Lucene::Search::Highlight`](http://search.cpan.org/~tbusch/Lucene-Search-Highlight-0.01/lib/Lucene/Search/Highlight.pm) and failed over and over again. Is there another I can get the relevant fragments of text that Lucene "thinks" they relevant for my search phrase?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways to do what you ask for, dependent on what you want:

1. See what strings matched for debugging purposes: Java Lucene has [explain()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_2_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20int%29) for this purpose. As Plucene should be similar, I suggest you look for explain() in the source code, as I failed to find it in the documentation.
2. Display matched strings to the user: Use the highlighter, as you tried to do. I suggest you post code with specific problems to SO and probably someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the words from query, Then

```
function highlightWords($text, $words)
{
  /*** loop of the array of words ***/
  foreach ($words as $word)
  {
    /*** highlight the words ***/
    $text = preg_replace("/\b($word)\b/i", 
            '<span style="color:red">\1</span>', $text);
  }
  /*** return the text ***/
  return $text;
}
```